# param is missing or the value is empty: purchase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass the following inside a def create method. The create method is in the transactions controller.

```
@purchases = current_shop.purchases.build(purchase_params)
@purchases.save!

private

def purchase_params
  params.require(:purchase).permit(:shop_id, :subscription_id, :created_at)
end
```

And returns this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in TransactionsController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: purchase
```

**Update 1**

Logs:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aJWUUEwgtG0o52MEHSOcNETj1Ueo+4NvLBD+y5LMPHxtHnOEe1Zgs3IMADdv5y+dbl7Ecgr8LMEjIG6sws9kqg==", "payment_method_nonce"=>"bf7458d2-d3a4-02c9-2593-526174f50822"}
  Cart Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 93], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Shop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = ? ORDER BY "shops"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  LineItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 93]]
  Subscription Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2899ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms) 

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: purchase):

app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:60:in purchase_params'
app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb:31:in create'
```

**Update 2**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>

<div class="form-container radius-box glassy-bg small-10 small-centered medium-8 large-6 columns">
  <h2 class="mbs">New Transaction</h2>
  <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
    <p>Please enter your payment details:</p>
    <div id="dropin"></div>
    <%=submit_tag "Pay #{@cart.total_price}$", class: "button mt1" %>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently `params` does not contain `purchase` key. Can you show your logs? Also show the form that sends the parameters.

Comment: Thans for the reply @Gerry.. please check out update 1 for more info.

Comment: You are just sending `"payment_method_nonce"=>"bf7458d2-d3a4-02c9-2593-526174f50822"}` in your params, no `purchase`. Please share your form, the problem should be there.

Comment: I updated again, providing more info

Comment: By form i meant the _view_ that sends the parameters to your controller, can you show it?

Comment: @Gerry... Update 2 again, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any `purchase` params.

Comment: @Dave Newton... do you mean inside the view?

Comment: I mean you're not sending any purchase params as shown by the params being logged. You're declaring then as required but not sending any.

Comment: @Theopap Yes, but i'm not sure that's the correct form, are you using javascript to set the values to be sent?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @Gerry!

Comment: Can you update the question with that javascript code?

Comment: Sure @Pavan...I'm using only this inside transactions.coffee $ ->
  unless typeof gon is 'undefined'
    braintree.setup(gon.client_token, 'dropin', { container: 'dropin' });

Comment: To be more specific I used the following tutorial to implement braintree checkout: https://www.sitepoint.com/integrate-braintree-payments-rails/

Comment: Step 2: Initialize Braintree